# How to read values from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor

Tags: asp.net-core

As the question points out i am trying to read route values from it such as the id or other parameters.

I made this base class

```
public abstract class PermissionAttributeBase : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor)
        {
            if (controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute)))
                return;

            if (!await IsAuthorizedAsync(new PermissionContext(filterContext, controllerActionDescriptor)))
                filterContext.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }

    protected abstract Task<bool> IsAuthorizedAsync(PermissionContext permissionContext);
}
```

However i can't seem to find a way to read the values from it. Are the values not available at the point of authorization perhaps?

I have tried many way but even something like this:

```
var read = permissionContext.FilterContext.ModelState.TryGetValue("id", out var val3);
```

returns no value at all.

Comment: Authz filters run before model-binding, so the `ModelState` isn't populated at this stage in the pipeline.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks for the pointer. time to dig in the source code i guess

Comment: I don't know your exact needs, but `HttpContext.GetRouteData` might be useful if you're just looking to pull out route values.

Comment: Why do you want to read it from the ControllerActionDescriptor? You can read the `RouteData` like `filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"]?.ToString()` or values from the query string like `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["id"].ToString()`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks. That indeed might be useful but i'll see if i can include modelbinding somehow. That could pose a useful feature in the end

Comment: @hujtomi that is sort of the issue. i dislike the idea of checking both and would like to utilize an access way which covers both Query/RouteData.Values - ideally verify the transmitted model as well. I'll keep the suggestion in mind though. When working with just id's that would indeed be enough

Answer (score 1):

For MVC The parameter values for action are available on the ActionExecutingContext not on ControllerActionDescriptor.

Try `ActionExecutingContext.ActionArguments`